# ExtJS calling me.items.push within store.load() not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

in arrayVals i have the data which i got from store when it got loaded, now i want to populate that data from arrayVals in Menu Items...if i call me.items.push outside load method it works fine with dummy data but when i call it in load method i am getting error i.e Object [object Object] has no method 'push'

```
items = [];
var arrayVals = [];
me.getUserCompanyLogStore().load({
  callback: function (records, operation, success) {
    success: {
      Ext.Array.each(records, function (record, index, array) {
        arrayVals.push(record.get("company"));
      });
      Ext.Array.each(arrayVals, function (record, index, array) {
        console.log(arrayVals)
        me.items.push({ // Object [object Object] has no method 'push'
          xtype: 'main-header-nav-FavoriteItem',
          text: record
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide full information, but this is the most likely scenario:

By the time the store has loaded, `items` is no longer an array of configuration options, because the container has already processed them. Instead, you need to call `me.add()`, since items is now a MixedCollection and the configuration processing stage has passed.

Comment: But there are items in the Menu
1) Frequent
2) Recent
3) Favorite
And i want to show the loaded data under Frequent...By using your solution the data is populating perfectly but gets loaded under Favorite Item...

Comment: hey, now it worked perfectly, i just placed the whole code outside success block within load function...and everything worked fine...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
var items = [];
var arrayVals = [];
var self = this;
me.getUserCompanyLogStore().load({
  callback: function (records, operation, success) {
    success: {
      Ext.Array.each(records, function (record, index, array) {
        arrayVals.push(record.get("company"));
      });
      Ext.Array.each(arrayVals, function (record, index, array) {
        console.log(arrayVals)
        self.items.push({ // Object [object Object] has no method 'push'
          xtype: 'main-header-nav-FavoriteItem',
          text: record
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you creating `items` with `var` keyword?